# Can't get HBase Stand-alone mode to start

Tags: hbase

I am going through the HBase QuickStart guide (http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html), and I am running into lots of problems getting through the first step.

I am using Mint Linux 13 under VirtualBox with Win7 as host.

I downloaded hbase 0.94.6.1, unzipped the file on my home path, configured the loopback address. I was fine with writing to /tmp for testing purposes, so I did not modify /conf/hbase-site.xml.

```
start-hbase.sh: 45: [: false: unexpected operator
localhost: starting zookeeper, logging to /home/askldjd/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-askldjd-zookeeper-test-hadoop.out
starting master, logging to /home/askldjd/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-askldjd-master-test-hadoop.out
Could not start ZK at requested port of 2181.  ZK was started at port: 2182.  Aborting as clients (e.g. shell) will not be able to find this ZK quorum.
localhost: starting regionserver, logging to /home/askldjd/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-askldjd-regionserver-test-hadoop.out
```

If I type ./bin/hbase shell, and enter status, here's what I get.

```
13/04/05 01:47:06 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
```

JAVA_HOME is configured.

```
askldjd@test-hadoop ~ $ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/
```

I think I am missing something very basic here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

... Alan

Comment: you have to updte hbase-site .xml and add hbase.root.dir path there

Comment: I have done that following the quick start guide. Same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `unexpected operator` message indicates you might have the same problem as I had:

Did you run it with `sudo sh start-hbase.sh`? Instead, try **`sudo ./start-hbase.sh`**.

I don't really know why, but `sh` seems not to be able to interpret square brackets. More details on the difference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22910/what-is-the-difference-between-and-sh-to-run-a-script

Answer (score 7):

According to the log message there is some problem starting zookeeper in its default port (2181)

*"Could not start ZK at requested port of 2181."*

Check whether any other process is running on port 2181, If so try to start hbase after stopping the process which is running on port 2181.

Or else

You can run zookeeper separately and tell hbase to use it.

To make hbase use the zookeeper which you run separately, the following changes has to be made

- HBASE_MANAGES_ZK variable in conf/hbase-env.sh has to be set to false (This tells hbase not to start its own zookeeper ensemble)
- Set the zookeeper value and its port in conf/hbase-site.xml

  ```
  <property>
     <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
     <value>localhost</value>
  </property>

  <property>
     <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
     <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  ```

Refer the following link for configuring and running zookeeper:

http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_InstallingSingleMode

Comment: According to http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#standalone_dist the /usr/lib/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml file needs to be configured as follows:<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>